# ui:inputselect with dropdownlist and button align horizontally on same line

Tags: lightning-design-system

I'm trying to align inputselect and button on same line horizontally

```
     <div class="slds-m-around--x-small">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-center slds-m-around--x-small">    
          <ui:inputselect label="Contact Type: " class="dynamic" aura:id="InputSelectDynamic" change="{!c.getFilteredContact}"/>
        </div>

       <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-end slds-m-around--x-small">
         <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.addSelected}">Process Selected</button>
       </div> 

     </div>
```

[image]

Comment: Try style="display:inline;".It worked for me.

Comment: Thanks Bretto. I tried to have style in my div for inputselect but still the label and drop down is in 2 diff lines. How to pull the drop down next to label

Comment: Try this:
<div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-center slds-m-around--x-small">    
        Contact Type: <ui:inputselect class="dynamic" aura:id="InputSelectDynamic" change="{!c.getFilteredContact}"/>
    </div>
And add class with display:inline-block; for the button to get all in same line.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new style class

```
.inline-block{
   display: inline-block;
}
```

Update the divs class attribute;

Component:

```
     <div class="slds-m-around--x-small">
        <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-center slds-m-around--x-small inline-block">    
          <ui:inputselect label="Contact Type: " class="dynamic" aura:id="InputSelectDynamic" change="{!c.getFilteredContact}"/>
        </div>

       <div class="slds-grid slds-grid--align-end slds-m-around--x-small inline-block">
         <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.addSelected}">Process Selected</button>
       </div> 

     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to use slds-grid in every div. So instead of that **use slds-grid in main div that will solve you Problem..**

```
<div class="slds-grid  slds-m-around--x-small">
     <div class="slds-grid--align-center slds-m-around--x-small">    
         <ui:inputselect label="Contact Type: " class="dynamic" aura:id="InputSelectDynamic" change="{!c.getFilteredContact}"/>
     </div>
     <div class="slds-grid--align-end slds-m-around--x-small">
         <button class="slds-button slds-button--brand" onclick="{!c.addSelected}">Process Selected</button>
     </div>          
</div>
```

Follow This for Better Understanding:

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lightning_design_system/units/lightning-design-system3
https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/grid/